# object when used in template gives error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using django framework for my project. I have an object which I am passing to template through views. The object works fine when I print its contents in views but give me an error when I use it in template html. I am using render_to_response function

```
render_to_response('template.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,request_params))
```

The error is

```
Value Error

Expected a Field, got a <type 'str'>
```

I am sending data in views to

```
 request_params = {'data':my_object}
 return render_to_response('template.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,request_params))
 #where my_object has variables like my_objects.variable1,my_objects.variable2
```

In template I am retrieving the data as:

```
...
{% if data %}
{{data.variable1}}
{% endif %}
```

Any idea how can I solve it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should return response:

```
return render_to_response('template.html',
                          request_params,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using **Django 1.4 +**. Get rid of long `render_to_response.` Do like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# In your view

return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'test':'test'})
```

Comment: Yes I am using version 1.5.2 .. Thanks sachitad but nothing changed, still got the same error

Comment: Post the full traceback now, will ya

Answer (score 0):

I got it .. I am using cached template loaders 'django.template.loaders.cached.Loader' and the changes to the template were not visible unless I restart the server. The values were retrieved after I restart the server.

**Thank you all for your help and assistance.**